# Compiler error c2237 when working with modules

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, c++-modules, visual-studio-2022

I am trying to change a project to use modules in visual studio. I have changed a simple class to generate a module as follows:

```
#pragma once

export module FieldData;

namespace Serializer
{
    class FieldData
    {
    public:
        bool nvConverted{ false };
    };
}
```

I've also changed the item type to 'c/c++ compiler' This results in the following error however:

> error C2237: multiple module declaration

Unfortunately there seems to be no documentation on what causes c2237 or how to resolve it

Comment: You probably still have files that `#include` this header.

Comment: I've double checked, but it doesn't look like it

Comment: @SebastianRedl Adding to that, when i do #include the file in other headers, I get multiple instances of the C2237 error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. The problem was that I hadn't changed the 'Compile as' option in the project properties -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced. The value it needs to be is: 'Compile as C++ Module Code (/interface )'